# Move data from existing column to new columns in Sequel pro

Tags: mysql, table, split

I need help with my SQL table, so thank you in advance for any comments. My table in Sequel Pro (example):

| Object | Time | Intensity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| . A. | . 1. | . 100. |
| . A. | . 2. | . 150. |
| . A. | . 3. | . 300. |
| . B. | . 1. | . 150. |
| . B. | . 2. | . 300. |
| . C. | . 1. | . 80. |
| . C. | . 2. | . 100. |
| . C. | . 3. | . 140. |
| . C. | . 4. | . 200. |

And I would like it to look like this:

| Time | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| . 1. | . 100. | . 150. | . 80. |
| . 2. | . 150. | . 300. | . 100. |
| . 3. | . 300. | . NULL | . 140. |
| . 4. | . NULL | . NULL | . 200. |

Thanks!

Comment: On SQL Server - use PIVOT.

Comment: Googling "Sequel Pro" this seems to be a UI usually used with MySQL and MariaDB. What database engine are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I think is MySQL.